# Speech to text API for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Can anyone provide sample integration or please let me know any 3rd party api for speech to text conversion in iphone ?

Thanks & Regards,
Tariq

Comment: SpinVox api provide these facilities.. but its not free version.. please let me know any free version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into CMU Sphinx and VocalKit (on github).

Comment: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have already tried VocalKit.... its not working for Speech to text conversion

Answer (score 0):

Using pocketsphinx it would be easier 
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

OpenEars – iPhone Voice Recognition and Text-To-Speech
http://www.politepix.com/openears/