# Speech to text Conversion Language Model?

Tags: iphone, speech-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speech to text API for iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598549/speech-to-text-api-for-iphone)

I am working on an application which need speech to text conversion feature. I am going to hit a radio feed url and audio coming from there would be converted to text.

After so much time spent on google I could not find good sources.  I came to know about OpenEars.  It needs Language model.  Can some one tell from where i can get language model any free or paid source.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/). As I remember they have the language model for speech recognition.