# convert voice into text

Tags: iphone, ios6, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speech to text API for iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598549/speech-to-text-api-for-iphone)

Currently, I am developing an App in which I have recorded the voice using AvAudioRecorder.

Its working fine for me but I also want that recorded voice also converted into text & text

save into text field automatically. I am goggling so much but can't succeeded. How can I solve

this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you searched?! There are dozens of [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition) [of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598549/speech-to-text-api-for-iphone) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347072/text-to-speech-on-iphone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Google and Siri and other sound recognition apps like SoundHound do this by uploading the sound to a server which then does all the heavy lifting and returns it to the device as text (or whatever is required).

Even dictation on the iPhone does this.

If you can get that to work on the device I'd be very impressed :D